# Python: How can I append without overriding past append for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I am currently trying to append to the output list in my code the id of the query result. I can get it to do one of the ids but it will override the first one how can I change my code to allow any amount of looping to the `output.append(q.id)`

Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/new-mealplan', methods=['POST'])
```

def create_mealplan():

```
data = request.get_json()
recipes = data['recipes']

output = []

for recipe in recipes:
    try:
        query = Recipes.query.filter(func.lower(Recipes.recipe_name) == func.lower(recipe)).all()
        # print(recipe)
        if query:
            query = Recipes.query.filter(func.lower(Recipes.recipe_name) == func.lower(recipe)).all()
            for q in query:
                output.append(q.id)
    finally:
        return jsonify({"data" : output})
```

Comment: Maybe initialize `output` outside the for loop?

Comment: Nope just tried that and is still just showing 1 of them.

Comment: I can only guess because I cannot really run your code without having the recipe data you have, but maybe you are returning too soon. Can you try returning after the loop has finished and see what happens?

Comment: That worked, I removed the try and finally and did the return after the loop finished.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I removed the
`Try` and `Finally` blocks.
Then returned after the for-loop was completed.